# WP7 : All area clickable in a Grid.Row

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I search the site and every where but seems no one knows about this problem.
Basically I want to make a Grid.Row clickable using Tap or any other event !
The problem is that It works but only on the places that there is a text in it. take a look at the picture , I want it to be clickable on even the empty space so basically the entire surface of the row.

[image]

I know its possible as many applications like Nokia transport or even Windows Phone Setting Page is like that and they work exactly in a way that I want my application work !

I have tried everything, I tried Tap event for Grid : Didn't work still only clickable on the text area only

I tried Stackpanel , no chance

I also tried Toolkit Gesture event and no chance

Can someone please help me with that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input events will fall through transparent areas. What I usually do in this case is use a background color that is almost transparent.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#01ffffff" Tap="UIElement_OnTap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">Test Block</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">3000</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In this example, note that each row in the outermost grid is another grid that spans the whole row and handles the **Tap** event.

Still, what's important in this example is the **Background="#01ffffff"**. This color is *almost transparent*, but is just opaque enough to catch the Tap event.

Good luck!

**EDIT:** While the previous answer works, it turns out you can also just set **Background="Transparent"**. The Background just has to be set to something and not be an unset value for touch events to be captured.